# On an approach on the Hilbert-Polya Conjecture suggested by Schumayer and Hutchison

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, riemann-zeta-function

In their expository paper, ''Physics of the Riemann Hypothesis arxiv.org/abs/1101.3116v1'', Hutchison and Schumayer suggested the following approach on the Hilbert Polya conjecture, via quantisation of the classical Hamiltonian $H=xp$.

They consider the dilation symmetry of this Hamiltonian $x\mapsto \lambda x, p \mapsto p/\lambda$) which manifests itself in the transformation of the corresponding wave function as

$$\varphi(\lambda x) = \frac{1}{\lambda^{1/2-iE}}\varphi(x)$$

and one might suggest restricting ourselves to λ being
a positive integer. They claim that this could be an attractive suggestion,
because the wave-packet, generated by the uniform
superpositions of all these transformed wavefunctions is

$$\psi(x) =\zeta(1/2 - iE)\varphi(x).$$

where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function and $E$ is real. They then state that however, there is no physical motivation which would
require this $\zeta$ pre-factor to vanish. Furthermore this
integer-based dilation-symmetry does not form a group,
because the multiplicative inverse element (which would
be $\lambda = 1/m$) is missing.

But even if one could find some physical motivation for the pre $\zeta$ factor to vanish, wouldn't it only imply that *some (not necessarily all)* zeros of $\zeta(1/2 -iE)$ are real, which is not suffficient for the Hilbert-Polya conjecture to be true ?

Comment: Isn't the whole problem of these types of Hamiltonians, that no one knows if they are hermitian (or at least $\mathcal{PT}$ inversion symmetric). And that this question is exactly the RH. And it seems to be everyone is exactly as far from proving that as he is from proving the RH.

Comment: you can find a recent criticism of this approach based on $H=(xp+px)/2$ in a [comment](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02644) by Jean Bellissard.

Comment: The authors addressed the comments. The conjecture is asking about the real part of a complex number, if the root is imaginary then the real part is simply zero. Also, the roots have been bounded in the range 0 to 1 already. So their proof is sufficient.